# Symfony2/Doctrine2 issue with query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am getting a weird response from a query which is messing things up.  Essentially, I make a call like so

```
$allFlights = $em->getRepository("NickAlertBundle:Alert")->getSpecificAlert($id);
```

This calls the following query

```
public function getSpecificAlert($id)
{
    $active = "Active";

    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT a.id, a.searchCommand,
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.classLetter) AS classes,
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.pseudo) AS pseudos,
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT f.flightNumber) AS flight_number
                    FROM NickAlertBundle:Alert a
                        JOIN NickAlertBundle:BookingClass c
                          WITH a.id = c.availabilityAlert
                        JOIN NickAlertBundle:Pseudos p
                          WITH a.id = p.availabilityAlert
                        JOIN NickAlertBundle:FlightNumbers f
                          WITH a.id = f.availabilityAlert
                    WHERE a.alertStatus = :active
                    AND a.id = :id
                    GROUP BY a.id'
        )
        ->setParameter('active', $active)
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->getResult();
}
```

Now in my database I have two alerts.  If I var_dump the response to that query, the first alert is

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(5) { 
        ["id"]=> int(3) 
        ["searchCommand"]=> string(12) "A20JUNLONMIA" 
        ["classes"]=> string(1) "I" 
        ["pseudos"]=> string(7) "12D,4FD" 
        ["flight_number"]=> string(6) "AY5507" 
    } 
}
```

Now this one processes fine.  If I output the second Alert I get the following

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(5) { 
        ["id"]=> int(8) 
        ["searchCommand"]=> string(20) "@BA@A20APRLONNYC0100" 
        ["classes"]=> string(1) "A" 
        ["pseudos"]=> string(7) "12D,4FD" 
        ["flight_number"]=> string(6) "BA1516" 
    } 
} 
array(0) { }
```

So it does it with an empty Array on the end.  There is only one alert with this id in the database, so not sure why this is happening.  Anyways, this empty array is causing the following to fail

```
$command = $allFlights[0]['searchCommand'];
```

Is there any reason why I may be receiving an empty array for this particular query?  It seems the occur for any command that starts with an @.

Thanks

Comment: the output of the second alert looks like two arrays , how does the function return two arrays ? (is that even possible ? :) ) is there another array wrapped the two together ?

Comment: Not that I know of.  That output is from a direct call to my repo, so not to sure why it is returning two arrays

Comment: @NickPrice: your code is messy. What do you mean with "command that starts with an @" ?

Comment: Hi Don.  What do you mean by messy?  I am always looking to improve so it will be good to know what needs improving.  The idea of what I am doing is you enter a command, receive a response, select some data from the response and then submit it.  If the initial command is something like A20APRLONLAX it works fine.  If the command is @BA@A20APRLONLAX then this is where I get the extra array which messes things up.  I am trying to work out why this is happening, plan on going through it properly today,